# can you re-sample a series without dates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time series from months 1 to 420 (35 years).  I would like to convert to an annual series using the average of the 12 months in each year so I can put in a dataframe I have with annual datapoints.  I have it setup using a range with steps of 12  but it gets kind of messy. Ideally would like to use the resample function but having trouble since no dates.  Any way around this?

Comment: What does your data look like?  If you have a date for each month you can extract the year for each observation into its own column then group on the year to calculate the average.

Comment: Just one column with month 1, 2,3.... and another with values (float 64).   type() is pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to resample in this case. Just use `groupby` with integer division to obtain the average over the years.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Months': np.arange(1,421,1),
                   'val': np.random.randint(1,10,420)})

# Create Yearly average. 1-12, 13-24, Subtract 1 before // to get this grouping
df.groupby((df.Months-1)//12).val.mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'Months': 'Year'})
```

Outputs:

```
    Year       val
0      0  3.083333
1      1  4.166667
2      2  5.250000
3      3  4.416667
4      4  5.500000
5      5  4.583333
...
31    31  5.333333
32    32  5.000000
33    33  6.250000
34    34  5.250000
```

Feel free to add `1` to the year column or whatever you need to make it consistent with indexing in your other annual `df`. Otherwise, you could just use `df.groupby((df.Months+11)//12).val().mean()` to get the `Year` to start at 1.

Comment: That works.  A little unclear where to put the 1 in order to shift the years.  Your code above goes from year 0 to 34. How would I switch to 1 to 35 for just the year column?

Comment: @ChrisL after you create the yearly DataFrame (call it `df_y`) you can just do: `df_y['Year'] = df_y['Year'] +1` to add one to the year column. There are other ways to get the same result, for instance in the groupby you could `groupby((df.Months+11)//12)`. The point is that integer division throws out the remainder, so (1 to 11)//12 = 0, while 12//12 = 1 and what you really want is (1 to 12)//12 to be associated with `Year = 1`